# send file with arabic name to mobile phone via bluetooth in python

Tags: python, bluetooth

i want send file with Arabic file name to mobile phone via bluetooth.

file name fetched from sqlite database and type of that is Unicode ...
i useed openobex python module to send file via bluetooth.

this is my python code :

```
    con = sqlite3.connect('/home/abbas/DataBase',detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES)  # @UndefinedVariable
    cur = con.cursor()
    path = '/home/abbas/001 (2).jpg'
    cur.execute('select vname from sendlist where path=?',(path,))
    data = cur.fetchall()
    vnametemp = data[0]
    vnametemp = vnametemp[0]
    te,et=os.path.splitext(path)
    vname = vnametemp+et
    print vname
    print type(vname)
    cl = obexftp.client(obexftp.BLUETOOTH)
    print cl.connectpush('6C:0E:0D:3A:1F:90',6,'hci0')
    #cl.put_file(local_file,remote_file_name)
    print cl.put_file(path,vname.encode('utf-8'))
```

and this is output :

```
تست جاوا2.jpg
<type 'unicode'>
1
```

and this is show in mobile when receiving file :

[image]

how i fix file name show in mobile ?

Comment: Does your phone use UTF-8 or other character encoding?

Comment: @Arcturil i don`n know. how can i know it ? ... but i test to send this file to android phone and same result .